# SceneKit - Texture mapping for different planes

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

I want to tile a custom plane in scenekit. Plane is a polygon that could have any shape.
Here is the `contentTransform` and uv source texture coordinates:

```
let textureCoordinates = [  CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
                            CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0),
                            CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1),
                            CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
//...

polygonDiffuse.contentsTransform = .init(m11: 2.5, m12: 0,    m13: 0,    m14: 0,
                                         m21: 0,    m22: 2.5, m23: 0,    m24: 0,
                                         m31: 0,    m32: 0,    m33: 1,    m34: 0,
                                         m41: 0,    m42: 0,   m43: 0,    m44: 1)
```

How should I change the texture mapping to prevent tiles being stretched for all polygon planes?

Answer (score 0):

Since you said 'any' shape, here are a couple of examples.  You'll have to rotate these into place.  You may have to adjust your texture, but yes - it will stretch.  If the image just "has to be square, you could do some math on the size of the dynamic polygon and center a quad panel inside of the Bezier outline, maybe use the same background to cover the overlap.

```
func getPentPanelSelectorNode(vPanelType: panelTypes, vUp: Int) -> SCNNode
    {
        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        
        bezierPath.move(to:    CGPoint(x: -6.9, y: -10.15))
        
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:  6.9, y: -10.15))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:  15.2, y:  3.22))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:  0.2, y:  13.40))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: -15.2, y:  3.22))
        bezierPath.close()
        
        let plane = SCNShape(path: bezierPath, extrusionDepth: 0.1)
        
        let topMaterial = SCNMaterial()
        topMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green
        topMaterial.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true
        plane.materials = [topMaterial]
        let vNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
}

func getTriPanelNode(vPanelType: panelTypes, vUp: Int) -> SCNNode
{

        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        bezierPath.move(to:    CGPoint(x: -2.0, y: -1.5))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:  2.0, y: -1.5))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:  0.0, y:  1.5))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: -2.0, y: -1.5))
        bezierPath.close()
        
        let plane = SCNShape(path: bezierPath, extrusionDepth: 0.0001)
        
        plane.materials = []
        plane.materials = setTriPanelTextures(vPanelType: vPanelType, vUp: vUp)
        plane.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = false
        
        let vNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
}
```

EDIT - I just tried to send you a couple of different examples of bezier paths.  These are just triangle and pentagon panels.

```
func setTriPanelTextures(vPanelType: panelTypes, vUp: Int) -> [SCNMaterial]
    {
        let topMaterial = SCNMaterial()
        switch vPanelType
        {
        case .normal:   topMaterial.diffuse.contents = "art.scnassets/Images/Panels/TileNormal.png"; break
        case .entry:    topMaterial.diffuse.contents = "art.scnassets/Images/Panels/TileEntryTri.png"; break
        case .exit:     topMaterial.diffuse.contents = "art.scnassets/Images/Panels/TileExitTri.png"; break
        case .path:     topMaterial.diffuse.contents = "art.scnassets/Images/Panels/TilePathTri.png"; break
        case .occupied: topMaterial.diffuse.contents = "art.scnassets/Images/Panels/TileNormal.png"; break
        }
        topMaterial.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true
        
        return [topMaterial]
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Voltan, your answer is strange to me, what is the setTriPanelTextures method? also I cant see where your are tiling the material? and what is the panelTypes?